# Elasticsearch node out of space due to large index size

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, graylog2, graylog

I have run out of space on the machine that is running my Graylog server.

A lot of the space is taken up with files in the

`/var/lib/elasticsearch/graylog2/nodes/0/indices/graylog2_0/0/index` folder.

- Is it safe to remove the files in this folder?
- Is this a problem with elastic search?
- How can I prevent this happening in the future?

Thanks,

Seán

Comment: Don't remove those files, as they are the index files for your graylog ES indices. Instead, you should look into the [curator tool](https://github.com/elastic/curator) if you need to wipe out some older indices.

Comment: How many repilca do u have for index `graylog2_0`?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently gone through this problem. I have few suggestions

***Is it safe to remove the files in this folder?***

No, its not safer way to free up space rather as suggested @Val you can delete old indices using [curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator).

But if you don't have older indices to removed I have few suggestion.

sol 1) If you have replica in you index and you have multiple elasticsearch node.
Then you can delete replica using live cluster settings and reroute the shard on other node.
Once routing done you can increase the replica size.

sol 2) Add new Elasitcseach node.

***Is this a problem with elastic search?***

No, its not Elasitcsearch problem if you have large amount of data indexing in your Elasticsearch cluster.

***How can I prevent this happening in the future?***

Set monitoring alert on your Elasticsearch server. may be on 90% limit. If your space is increases more than 90% its should send you alert message.